# Copy/paste not working as expected in Ubuntu running a KDE Plasma session

Tags: kde, clipboard

I switched from Gnome to KDE (5 Plasma) recently, but am unable to copy text from some applications.

- In Kate, I copy some text (either using ctrl+C, or with right-click-copy).
- I paste (either ctrl-V, or right-click-paste) and some old text gets pasted -- text I copied a few hours ago.
- in the context menu, "clipboard history", I can see the text I just copied, as if it had copied correctly.
- I switch to any other application and I cannot paste that new text either.

It's not specific to Kate:

- Exactly the same problem when copying/pasting in Konsole, and in Dolphin.

But other applications can copy fine...

- I switch to Matlab, and copy some text to the clipboard (alt+W, or right-click-copy)
- I paste the text (ctrl+Y, or right-click paste), and the new text pastes correctly
- I switch to Kate/Konsole, and paste, and the new text copied from Matlab pastes correctly!!!
- Similarly, I can copy text OK from Firefox, and from Libre Office.

System info:

```
$ plasmashell --version
plasmashell 5.12.8

$ kf5-config --version
Qt: 5.9.5
KDE Frameworks: 5.44.0
kf5-config: 1.0

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

$ kate --version
kate 17.12.3

% dpkg -l | grep plasma-desktop
ii  plasma-desktop   4:5.12.9.1-0ubuntu0.1
```

So it seems to be copying from specific programs that is broken. Any thoughts on how I can go about debugging this? Is this some incompatibility between GTK, Qt and KDE? I have tried:

- disabling System Tray Settings / General / Extra / Clipboard
- re-enabling Clipboard
- restarting computer of course.

Comment: How did you do this: "I switched from Gnome to KDE (5 Plasma)"? I'm asking because I have the same software versions but don't see any problems re. copy/paste. The notable difference is that my system is a clean install of Kubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I used `sudo tasksel install kubuntu-desktop` and `sudo apt install sddm`, about 6 months after installing bionic from canonical. All seemed to go smoothly at the time but I am suspicious(!)  I'd really rather not re-install...

Comment: What happens if you log into a GNOME session? Do the same combinations of applications give you the same problems?

Comment: Take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/982597/how-does-clipboard-work

Comment: The same problem here on Kubuntu 18.04. At some very rare times the clipboard functionality can come back without restarting the incapacitated Konsole/Kate, but after closing some other windows.